# Rename the IMAGE tag of a running container with docker

Tags: docker, containers

Just created a docker image with a Dockerfile and started a new docker container using the image previously built. After running the container, I execute "docker ps" and I see the name of the image used by the container in the IMAGE column. This is expected.

After that, I renamed the TAG of my docker image:

```
docker image tag <old-image> <new-image>
```

At this point, "docker images" reports two images with exactly the same IMAGE_ID, but different TAG.

Now I remove the initial *old-image* image.

```
docker rmi <old-image>
```

Now "docker images" reports just a single image with TAG *new-image*. At this point, when I execute docker ps, I see my container is using the IMAGE_ID on the IMAGE column, not the image TAG *new-image*.

I know if I create a new container, that new container will use the proper image TAG *new-image*. However, I would like to learn if it's possible to change this, without creating a new container.

Is this possible in some way? How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: I've encountered it before and I think the best solution is re-building the image with your new tag

Comment: Yes, that is the easy way, I know. I just wanted to learn how to do without re-building the image and starting a new container

Comment: Stop/delete the current container and launch it again with the new reference. Note: this is a pure display problem, your container is using the exact same image content. You actually did not rename/delete any image in you above example but simply changed a reference (i.e. `image_naem:tag`) pointing to the same image id. My thought: don't bother, it will show the correct image name on your next deployment.

Comment: I know the next container will be created fine. I just want to know if it's possible to edit the current container and update that tag.

Comment: In general, no, it's not possible to "edit the current container" (there are very limited exceptions), and rebuilding the image and recreating the container is an extremely standard workflow.